# How do I insert an ip address into mysql

Tags: mysql, node-red

good morning

im new to node red and javascript so this may be a simple issue im having
im trying to insert an ip address into a mysql table
in mysql i set the field to varchar(20)

> 9/28/2019, 9:08:38 AMnode: 7bfc4d89.726dbc
>
> msg : error
>
> "Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[object Object])' at line 1"

the basic flows are as follows:

```
[
  {
    "id": "df624ad9.0db0f8",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "661acf87.d0306",
    "name": "Defining inside ip",
    "func": "global.set(\"inside_ip\",msg.payload);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 530,
    "y": 120,
    "wires": [
      []
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "400e4f07.42965",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "661acf87.d0306",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "1",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": true,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "x": 190,
    "y": 120,
    "wires": [
      [
        "f3f24f92.29582"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "f3f24f92.29582",
    "type": "ip",
    "z": "661acf87.d0306",
    "name": "ip",
    "https": false,
    "timeout": "5000",
    "internalIPv4": true,
    "internalIPv6": false,
    "publicIPv4": false,
    "publicIPv6": false,
    "x": 330,
    "y": 120,
    "wires": [
      [
        "df624ad9.0db0f8"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "47202c3d.71ebfc",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "661acf87.d0306",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "1",
    "payloadType": "num",
    "repeat": "1",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": true,
    "onceDelay": "5",
    "x": 230,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
      [
        "20c745e0.57fb2a"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "7bfc4d89.726dbc",
    "type": "mysql",
    "z": "661acf87.d0306",
    "mydb": "ca2479e3.1dda58",
    "name": "",
    "x": 510,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
      []
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "20c745e0.57fb2a",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "661acf87.d0306",
    "name": "",
    "func": "msg.topic =\"INSERT INTO`node`(`inside_ip`) VALUES(\" +  global.get(\"inside_ip\") +  \")\";\nreturn msg;\n",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 350,
    "y": 180,
    "wires": [
      [
        "7bfc4d89.726dbc"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "ca2479e3.1dda58",
    "type": "MySQLdatabase",
    "z": "",
    "host": "72.90.182.40",
    "port": "3306",
    "db": "mysql_test",
    "tz": "eastern"
  }
]
```

However
if i set the "ip" like this it works:

```
[

  {
    "id": "1f5e06b6.76e931",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "87908bbe.239128",
    "name": "Defining inside ip",
    "func": "global.set(\"inside_ip\",msg.payload);\nreturn msg;",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 645,
    "y": 228,
    "wires": [
      []
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "4dd624b5.e58f34",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "87908bbe.239128",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "",
    "payloadType": "date",
    "repeat": "1",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": true,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "x": 305,
    "y": 228,
    "wires": [
      [
        "b9528c26.ceca2"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "b9528c26.ceca2",
    "type": "ip",
    "z": "87908bbe.239128",
    "name": "ip",
    "https": false,
    "timeout": "5000",
    "internalIPv4": true,
    "internalIPv6": false,
    "publicIPv4": false,
    "publicIPv6": false,
    "x": 445,
    "y": 228,
    "wires": [
      []
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "215d3000.15a8b8",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "87908bbe.239128",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "1",
    "payloadType": "num",
    "repeat": "1",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": true,
    "onceDelay": "5",
    "x": 345,
    "y": 288,
    "wires": [
      [
        "fdcd98f2.a35838"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "17946cb4.862c23",
    "type": "mysql",
    "z": "87908bbe.239128",
    "mydb": "59bd1ef5.938c2",
    "name": "",
    "x": 625,
    "y": 288,
    "wires": [
      []
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "fdcd98f2.a35838",
    "type": "function",
    "z": "87908bbe.239128",
    "name": "",
    "func": "msg.topic =\"INSERT INTO`node`(`inside_ip`) VALUES(\" +  global.get(\"inside_ip\") +  \")\";\nreturn msg;\n",
    "outputs": 1,
    "noerr": 0,
    "x": 465,
    "y": 288,
    "wires": [
      [
        "17946cb4.862c23"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "a248bafe.b02ac",
    "type": "inject",
    "z": "87908bbe.239128",
    "name": "",
    "topic": "",
    "payload": "\"192.168.1.1\"",
    "payloadType": "str",
    "repeat": "",
    "crontab": "",
    "once": true,
    "onceDelay": 0.1,
    "x": 341,
    "y": 145,
    "wires": [
      [
        "1f5e06b6.76e931"
      ]
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "59bd1ef5.938c2",
    "type": "MySQLdatabase",
    "z": "",
    "host": "72.90.182.40",
    "port": "3306",
    "db": "mysql_test",
    "tz": "eastern"
  }
]
```

any advise would be great

regards mike

Comment: The problem ist that AMnode should be AM, node and that is problably what is causing the problem, but your example didn't include B< AMnode so that it is hard to tell where the probLem is coming from.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so the IP node you are using returns the following in msg.payload

> {"internalIPv4":"192.168.1.107"}

For you to be able to save it to the database you need to crop the:

> ({"internalIPv4":" and "}

there are a couple of ways to do this by using the function node.

The first, one is to replace the unnecessary string with nothing (this is my way to go!)

```
 var str = JSON.stringify(msg.payload)       
 var ip = str.replace('{"internalIPv4":"', ''); 
 ip = ip.replace('"}', '')
 msg.payload = ip
 return msg;
```

The second method is to crop by character number

```
   var str = JSON.stringify(msg.payload)
   var ip = str.substring(17,30 );
   msg.payload = ip
   return msg;
```

The problem with this code is if the length of your IP changes, possibly one number from IP will be missing.

Both of these functions return me the same message (first is before function, the second is after)

> {"internalIPv4":"192.168.1.107"}
>
> "192.168.1.107"

Four more hints on your small project:
 1. No need to send the SQL query every second.

2. Better use some unique identifier (if running on raspberry pi use its serial number to identify which IP is for what device)
3. Add UNIQUE key on MYSQL for the IP addresses
4. Where you cant use", use ' (especially in fitting data in a MySQL query)

Hope I helped!